# Is there a faster way than using a for loop way to check for greyscale in python

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I am trying to write a function which determines if an image is grayscale or not, and then convert to grayscale if not, and return that image at the end.

The for loop code below works fine, but it's very slow. Is there a faster way to check for this? I looked through CV2 documentation but couldn't find anything offhand.

```
import cv2
def grey():
    img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
    for x in range(img.shape[0]):
        for y in range(img.shape[1]):
            if img[x,y,0] == img[x,y,1] == img[x,y,2]:
                grey = img
            else:
                grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return grey
```

Comment: Your code is  slow because you convert the whole image to grayscale again and again, every time you find a colored pixel!

Comment: It would be much faster to just always convert to grayscale, even if you're doing it for an image that doesn't need it. At least then all your input images will be in a consistent format.

Comment: For loading the image in grayscale irrespective whether the input image is grayscale or RGB, you can use the following: `img = cv2.imread('myImg.jpg', 0)`